# Can H2o AutoML benefit from a GPU instance on Sagemaker platform?

Tags: gpu, h2o, amazon-sagemaker, automl

I'm running some projects with H2o AutoML using Sagemaker notebook instances, and I would like to know if H2o AutoML can benefit from a GPU Sagemaker instance, if so, how should I configure the notebook?

Comment: Can you share more about how you are using H2O AutoML and what version of H2O it is?

Comment: @ErinLeDell, for sure! I believe it's the 3.2 version of H2O AutoML. I work as a management consultant, as part of my job I use ML to predict the likelihood of events as well as predicting continuous variables using regression. Addiotanly, I've been using ML for forecasting. Specifically, I'm in a project which I need to predict the likelihood of an investment portfolio to fall in a window of time.  In this project, I'll need to train a huge dataset, and then, I thought I could take advantage of GPU processing to reduce the training time. Usually, I use notebooks on Sagemaker.

Comment: You might want to double-check the version number, we are at 3.26 right now, so it's probably something close to that.

Comment: Yes, @ErinLeDell I realized it's the 3.26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[H2O AutoML](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html) contains a handful of algorithms and one of them is [XGBoost](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html), which has been part of H2O AutoML since H2O version 3.22.0.1.  XGBoost is the only GPU-capable algorithm inside of H2O AutoML, however, a lot of the models that are trained in AutoML are XGBoost models, so it still can be useful to utilize a GPU. Keep in mind that you must use H2O 3.22 or above to use this feature.

My suggestion is to test it on a GPU-enabled instance and compare the results to a non-GPU instance and see if it's worth the extra cost.

Comment: Thanks, @ErinLeDell. Do I need any additional set-up to enable de GPU instance to work with H2O AutoML? Like, install some libraries or anything else?

Comment: You need to check that you have Nvidia GPUs and CUDA 8 installed.  You can monitor the GPU usage during the AutoML run via the command line using the `nvidia-smi` command.

Comment: Thanks, @ErinLeDell, another doubt! To get both installed, can I only install CUDA Toolkit? I saw on Cuda's website that the most recent version of CUDA is 10.1.243, could I install that version(10) or I need specifically to install the version 8?

Comment: @Erin LeDell, can the H2O AutoML XGBoost utilize TPU in Google Colab?

Comment: @Md.HishamurRahman No, there's no TPU support, just GPU.